# How to delete an array inside a user-defined function?

Tags: arrays, awk, gawk

In awk, one can delete a previously defined array using the following command:

```
delete array;
```

or:

```
for (i in array)
{
    delete array[i];
}
```

Is it possible to define a user function that gets the array as an input and then deletes it? For example:

```
function delarr(arrname)
{
    delete arrname;
}

BEGIN {
    array[1] = "1";
    array[2] = "2";

    print array[1];

    delarr(array);
}
```

Comment: It works fine in `GNU Awk`

Comment: You wrote a script that does exactly what you want and then posted it and asked us how to do it. It never occurred to you to try what you wrote first?

Comment: Well, I did not post what I initially tested. The above is more like an air-code, but once tested *that*, I realized I had the answer. My bad...

Comment: Still, the accepted answer has a value in pointing out the reference documentation, specifying the difference between the two types of objects, which makes it from an empirical finding into a "certified" answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example just works.

From the [gawk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Pass-By-Value_002fReference.html):

> In awk, when you declare a function, there is no way to declare explicitly whether the arguments are passed by value or by reference.
>
> Instead, the passing convention is determined at runtime when the function is called, according to the following rule: if the argument is an array variable, then it is passed by reference. Otherwise, the argument is passed by value.

---

[POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html#tag_04_06_13_15) recommends the same behaviour:

> Function parameters shall be passed by value if scalar and by reference if array name.

Comment: Thanks. Does this mean that the example snippet should work?

Comment: Yes. Doesn't it?

Comment: Apparently, it does. I wrote a short tester and it seems that deleting the array inside the function does the job. Thanks.